# Limitation of number of predictions in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I’ve trained a Faster R-CNN model with Tensorflow Object Detection API with and encountered a strange issue. The output of the model has **max 100 predictions**, despite, there are many more objects in the image. This is a case for each image I’ve tested.

I’ve found similar issue on Ten GitHub, but from what I can see they are not doing much in these regards.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30464

Maybe you had a similar issue in the past? Any idea how to tackle this?

[image: example image]

Comment: Just for personal curiosity, did you test whether changing the mad detections per class and max total detection parameters on a trained network causes problems loading pretrained weights? I'd be really interested to know, as Icurrently don't have a test setup to try thison myself

Comment: No, this does not caused an issue. But there is another issue with evaluation process during training - Coco evaluator is not able to handle more than 100 dets. So the training process is going fine, but the metrics are not reflecting the real performance of the model. I've described the issue in details here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30464#issuecomment-519393486

Comment: Thanks! That's very good to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit of 100 is per class, then you have a max total detections of 300.

This is a network configuration parameter set in the `pipeline.config` file, in the `second_stage_post_processing` section. For example, the current `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config` has:

```
second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
```

Alter these values before you train your net (although I don't know how changing them affects the network size and/or whether it causes problems when using pretrained checkpoints for fine-tuning)

Comment: The accepted answer resolves the problem during training. However, there is an issue with evaluation process during training - Coco evaluator is not able to handle more than 100 dets. So the training process is going fine, but the metrics are not reflecting the real performance of the model. I've described the issue in details here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30464#issuecomment-519393486